# trying to mount secondary drive

Tags: mount, backup-restoration, centos6.4

centos 6 64bit

Trying to mount a BACKUP drive used previously on another server prior to a recent primary drive hard drive failure.

```
root@server097 [~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003cb32

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       19458   155777024   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_server097-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_server097-lv_swap: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_server097-lv_home: 101.6 GB, 101598625792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12351 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

root@server097 [~]# mount /dev/sda2 /backup
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

I only want to mount /dev/sda2 (this is the secondary drive) but getting the above error. I want to mount it to /backup

```
root@server097 [~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda2   VG vg_server097   lvm2 [148.56 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [148.56 GiB] / in use: 1 [148.56 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

root@server097 [~]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "vg_server097" using metadata type lvm2

root@server097 [~]# lvscan 
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server097/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server097/lv_home' [94.62 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_server097/lv_swap' [3.94 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: /dev/sda2 is part of a LVM group, you can't mount it. Provide `pvscan`, `vgscan`, and `lvscan` for details.

Comment: @fuero ok updated my original post with that info

Comment: If /dev/sda1 isn't mounted (`cat /proc/mounts`), try mounting that. It doesn't seem to be referenced by anything you provided.

Comment: this is the output http://tny.cz/5319ae35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/sda2` is part of a LVM group, you can't mount it.

No other evidence you provided suggests presence of another disk. All LVM volumes/parts of sda are mounted and in use, according to `/proc/mounts`